# Any script or character set that has upper vs. lower distinction on characters other than letters?

Tags: orthography

Scripts or character sets that have lower and upper case versions on letters are called bicameral (Roman, Greek and Cyrillic) and other scripts where there is no such casing are called unicameral.

Are there scripts that distinguish upper vs. lower case on characters apart from letters, say punctuation marks, digits on numbers or other symbols?

Comment: Even the normal Latin alphabet has the distinction between [text and lining figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures).

Comment: @curiousdannii: That is not upper- and lowercase.

Comment: @sumelic [Lining and text figures are generally considered to be upper and lower case respectively](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/54423/44848)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: There are uppercase and lowercase Roman Numerals; does this count as an example?

Comment: @jknappen, I think they do, since they have Unicode values separate from  identical looking Roman letters. Thanks.

Comment: @curiousdannii, although text figures are considered lowercase, they fall short of full acceptance since they do not have separate Unicode encoding.

Comment: If we go by Unicode, then the separate Roman numeral glyphs are not considered upper and lower.

Comment: I think the best hope is some accent mark or punctuation.

Comment: When one considers development of minuscule letters from the majuscule alphabet; one realises it was their frequency of usage coupled with the need to writhe fast which led to joining of characters which in turn led to their development: Now quite possibly it was only your regular letters which posed this imperative and not other glyphs (assuming they were there in the first place)

Comment: A related question on the now public beta Latin Language stackexchange: http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/332/when-did-the-latin-alphabet-become-bicameral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the closest thing coming to your question are the Greek Numeral signs Stigma and Digamma (6), Qoppa (90), and Sanpi (900) that aren't used as letters anymore, but have uppercase and lowercase forms.

There are also uppercase and lowercase Roman Numerals.

Note that bicameral scripts are rare (compared to the number of writing systems), there are only three fully bicameral scripts (Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic), and one that once was bicameral (Georgian). [I don't know how bicameral Glagolitic is, at least it has both cases in Unicode.]

Comment: I don't know whether I should accept your answer. Although sanpi, qoppa and digamma/stigma have separate Unicode codepoints for lowercase and uppercase variants, these are letters while at the same time used as numerals as well? I prefer the Roman numerals you mentioned in a comment.

Comment: If we go by Unicode, then the separate Roman numeral glyphs are not considered upper and lower.  (Whereas the Greek letters are, well, letters.)

Comment: I have chosen this as the correct answer. Seems like there's a lot of letters that alternates as mathematical letters with both [lowercase](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm) and [uppercase](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm) variants, as well as mathematical [numerals](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm) and [symbols](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm) with regular and small variants.

Answer (score 3):

According to python, not in the [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) (UCS-2):

```
import sys
for i in range(0, sys.maxunicode): # 0x10000
    c = unichr(i)
    if (not c.isalpha()) and (c.islower() or c.isupper()):
        print c.encode('utf-8')
# This code prints nothing
```

However, one could reasonably disagree with the Unicode Consortium's view that a combined glyph Roman numeral `u'Ⅺ'` (8554) is not uppercase and `u'ⅺ'` (8570) is not lowercase.

The Roman letters I, X, M and and Greek letters Stigma and Digamma, Qoppa, and Sanpi and so on are technically letters.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koppa_(letter) etc)

Hence

```
>>> u'ϟ'.isalpha() and u'ϙ'.isalpha() and u'ϡ'.isalpha()
True
```

If we consider [the cedilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedilla) (0327), there are cases where it takes different forms based on the casing of the letter it graces:
`u'Ģ'` vs `u'ģ'`.

Comment: You can configure python to use UTF-32 with `./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I wrote "not a letter", I was thinking of a letter with pure alphabetic usage. Although I also wrote "digits on numbers" , letters with numerical usage will do for my purpose.

Comment: Understand.  I would say every letter is used as a non-letter in some context.  In the Latin alphabet, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98_(disambiguation) is particularly overloaded, although in theory people in 2016 should use different Unicode chars for the different non-letter uses.